# Angular 8.2 Shared component that extends another component throws No component factory error

Tags: angular

I am currently doing some refactoring on an application, namely some forms.
I noticed they were all similar. Before the refactor they were working, but when I added the new **parent** class and extended it, I started getting this error for the child components:

> ERROR Error: No component factory found for SaveCategoryComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

My **parent** component looks like this:

```
import { OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

import { BaseModel, Attempt } from '@models';
import { NotificationService } from 'src/app/_shared/notification/notification.service';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class SaveComponent implements OnInit {
    public formGroup: FormGroup;
    public submitted: boolean;
    public notifications: object;
    public isEditing: boolean;

    // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
    get f() {
        return this.formGroup.controls;
    }

    constructor(
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public model: BaseModel,
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<any>,
        public notificationService: NotificationService,
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.isEditing = !!this.model.id;
    }

    public onSave(callback: (model: any) => Observable<any>) {
        this.submitted = true;

        if (this.formGroup.valid) {
            callback(this.formGroup.value).subscribe(
                (response: Attempt<BaseModel>) => {
                    if (response.failure) {
                        this.notificationService.show(`${response.error.message}`, 'danger');
                    } else {
                        this.notificationService.show(`Successfully saved your category.`, 'success');
                        this.formGroup.reset();
                    }

                    this.submitted = false;
                    this.dialogRef.close(response.result);
                },
                () => {
                    this.submitted = false;
                },
            );
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, it is looking for some data which in this case is `BaseModel`:

```
export interface BaseModel {
    id: string | number;
}
```

And my category looks like this:

```
import { BaseModel } from './base-model';

export class Category implements BaseModel {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    image: string;
    active: boolean;
}
```

Those all compile and look fine.
Then I have the **child** which looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { SaveComponent } from '../save.component';

import { Category } from '@models';
import { CategoryService } from '@services';
import { NotificationService } from '../../notification/notification.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-save-category',
    templateUrl: './save-category.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./save-category.component.scss'],
})
export class SaveCategoryComponent extends SaveComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public model: Category,
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<SaveCategoryComponent>,
        public notificationService: NotificationService,

        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private categoryService: CategoryService,
    ) {
        super(model, dialogRef, notificationService);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
            id: [this.model.id, Validators.required],
            name: [this.model.name, Validators.required],
            image: [this.model.image],
            active: [this.model.active],
        });
        super.ngOnInit();
    }

    public save() {
        const method = this.isEditing ? 'update' : 'create';
        this.onSave(this.categoryService[method]);
    }
}
```

This is part of my **shared** module, and is **declared**, **exported** and added as an **entryComponent**:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        RouterModule,
        FormsModule,           

        MatAutocompleteModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatRadioModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        AlertDialogComponent,
        ConfirmationDialogComponent,
        SaveBrandComponent,
        SaveCategoryComponent,
    ],
    exports: [
        AlertDialogComponent,
        ConfirmationDialogComponent,
        SaveBrandComponent,
        SaveCategoryComponent,
    ],
    providers: [DecimalPipe],
    entryComponents: [
        NotificationComponent,
        UploadImagesComponent,

        AlertDialogComponent,
        ConfirmationDialogComponent,
        SaveBrandComponent,
        SaveCategoryComponent,
    ],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

(I have removed any code from the module that isn't related at all)
I also have a dialog service I created (which was working before I created the **parent**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DialogService {
    constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}

    public open(component: any, model: any): MatDialogRef<any> {
        const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

        dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
        dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
        dialogConfig.data = model;

        return this.dialog.open(component, dialogConfig);
    }
}
```

And then in my main component, I do something like this:

```
openEditModal(model: Category) {
    const modalRef = this.dialogService.open(SaveCategoryComponent, model);

    modalRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result: Category) => {
        if (result) {
            this.updateItem(result);
            this.notificationSvc.show('You have successfully updated ' + result.name);
        }
    });
}
```

All this was working before I created the `SaveComponent`. As soon as I try to extend it, I get the error above. I know the component **is** defined in **entryComponents** in the shared module, so I have no idea what it's complaining about.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `SaveComponent` to the entry components array as well? Just as a hail mary, I can see how this may be required due to a bug and masked in the error message. Same for maybe any combination of `exports` and `declarations`

Comment: I can't because it doesn't have a `@component` decorator :(

Comment: Hmm I read somewhere (don't ask me where) that in Component inheritance the `@Component` decorators are merged together (fields from the child override those of the parent). I think you can safely add that decorator and override the values, maybe that's even required for it to function properly.

Comment: I will give it a go, but I am fairly sure you can't :) hang tight and I will report back!

Comment: I've googled "component inheritance Angular" and the first 3 relevant results all use the `@Component` decorator on their base component, like [here](https://blog.bitsrc.io/component-inheritance-in-angular-acd1215d5dd8#f040). They give dummy templates and styles and override those in the children. Hopefully it has something to do with your issue

Comment: It doesn't appear to be. I added the `@component` and then added it to `declarations` and `entryComponents` and still no joy

Comment: I even add it to the `exports` but that didn't work either (all this is in my shared module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent hours on this and could not fix it. Then I found a post that mentioned that entryComponents are not used in Angular 9, so I updated all my packages following this guide:

https://update.angular.io/

When I did this, I started getting new errors.
I went through it all and eventually I found that my `AppModule` required both `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` to be imported. When I did this, everything started working.

In the interest of science, I decided to go back to my original branch and try importing those modules to see if that fixed the issue in 8.2. It did **not**, so I have no idea how to fix it there.
The only solution I found was upgrading :(